# Changing class of elements not working properly on blogger.com

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, blogger

I want to make the elements "Edit View, Share, Delete" of the homepage of blogger.com visible. The div containing the elements has `class='blogg-visible-on-select'` (highlighted on image).

[image]

I tried to change the class of these divs to something else but when I do so, this happens:

[image]

I am not versed in JavaScript, and I am just using this script from searching on the internet and using what I know.

```
var elms = document.querySelectorAll(".blogg-visible-on-select");

for(var i=0; i<elms.length; i++)
{
    elms[i].className="None";
}
```